# how do I spread exponential number to array?

Tags: javascript

I have a number `1e+30`. I want to create an array with each digit in an index in the array.

Eg:

256 -> [...(256 + "")] -> ["2", "5", "6"]

I can't do that to `1e+30`. I get `NaN`. How do I do this?

Comment: Doing `[...(1e+30 + "")]` gives `["1", "e", "+", "3", "0"]`. How are you getting `NaN`?

Comment: fun fact `1e30 === 1000000000000000019884624838656` in JS. In this case it might be simpler to do this manually, instead of using a number.

Comment: `[...(1e+30).toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false})]`

Comment: @Amy apologies, I read your comment too fast

Comment: I see, `[...(256 + "")]` is coercing the number 256 into a string, and then uses the spread syntax to explode it into an array.

Comment: To echo @Thomas, `1e+30` is not really "a number". It's a string describing a value that you'd like *approximated* by a JavaScript binary floating-point number. I realize that that seems overly pedantic, but it's important.

Comment: why the downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution you can do is to use `.toLocaleString` to get the scientific notation into a string, and then split.

```js
const stringified = (1e+30).toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false});
const array = stringified.split("");
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) and convert the value to a string. The problem is the accuracy of the value.

```js
var value = 1e30,
    array = Array.from(BigInt(value).toString());

console.log(array.join(''));
console.log(array);
```

For an accurate value, you could calculate the value directly as `bigint` type.

```js
var array = Array.from((BigInt(10) ** BigInt(30)).toString());

console.log(array.join(''));
console.log(array);
```